# IWD Store Locator

Tags: magento2.2.6

I have installed IWD Store locator. Initially the search button was working but as i configured the Google Map API the search button stopped working. Another issue is from starting "Filter by Radius" option is not reflecting any change. It is taking the parameters which i have passed initially after changing those parameters it is not responding.
I have flushed the Cache, cleared the browsing history but no change.

Comment: Can you able to find any logs in magento, server and browser console

Comment: No. The extension is not responding to any change which i am making through admin panel except the Google Map API.